# Connect to resources in different Azure vNets from a single vNet Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm struggling on finding correct documentation that answers my specific question - so hoping the community can help me on my question please

**I'd like to know if I can use a single Virtual Network Gateway to connect to other resources in other vNets from the VPN connection from the "User" end please?**

The Virtual Network Gateway is SKU VpnGw2 Gen2 and is a Point-to-site configuration

Both Virtual Machines have no Public IP addresses - connectivity via the VPN connection is to the private IP addresses of each VM

Both Network Security Groups have NO inboud/outbound default rules set for RDP/port3389 - but all other default rules are in-place when initially creating the VM - including the AllowVnetInBound Any/Any/VirtualNetwork/VirtualNetwork/Allow

On the Core vNet's Peering settings I have enabled the option "Use this virtual network's gateway or Route Server"

On the Spoke vNet's Peering settings I have enabled the option "Use the remote virtual network's gateway or Route Server"

As the "User" (via VPN) - I can RDP to the Core VM successfully

**As the "User" (via VPN) - I cannot RDP to the Spoke VM successfully. Is this possible in this configuration or is there something else required?**

(When the "User" is RDP connected to the Core VM - from there I can initiate another RDP session inside that Core VM to the Spoke VM successfully)

Thank you in advance

[Click Here for image of topology described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wzNA.png)

Comment: Make sure that the Network Security Groups associated with the VMs in both the Core and Spoke VNets allow incoming RDP traffic from the VPN client's IP address

Comment: Hi @Venkat thanks for the reply - I've edited my initial question above to include information about the NSG and rulesets - I can connect in OK to the Core VM via RDP with the default AllowVnetInBound - Allow rule included

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks to @Venkat V for replying with a answer

The answer is actually simple - if you make any additions/changes to your vNets or any peering changes AFTER you've created the Virtual Network Gateway point-to-site configuration...

**RE-DOWNLOAD THE VPN CLIENT ZIP PACKAGE and reinstall on your local device - it contains important route table changes not present in the original package**

I don't think I've seen this mentioned in any of the documentation - it's been a long learning curve this one